# Equal padding for items displayed with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

I have a list of items that I want to be displayed with 6 on the top and 7 on the bottom. However items that longer words are not being centrally aligned.

This is currently what it looks like.

As you can see Outcome/KPI is not centrally aligned but others are.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is currently my code

```js
<div className="innerTabs">
    {Object.values(title).map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <h1
        className={color === index ? "activate" : "inactive"}
        onClick={() => {
            setPage(index);
            setColor(index);
        }}
        >
        {" "}
        {item}{" "}
        </h1>
    );
    })}
</div>
```

```css
.innerTabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.innerTabs h1 {
  flex: 0 0 calc(16.66% - 20px);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.innerTabs h1:hover {
  color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#contractNotes {
  width: 300px;
}

h1.activate {
  color: #6610f2;
  background: var(--light-opacity-color-primary-primary-16, rgba(115, 103, 240, 0.16));
  border-radius: 26px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h1.activate:hover {
  color: #6610f2;
  background: var(--light-opacity-color-primary-primary-16, rgba(115, 103, 240, 0.16));
  border-radius: 26px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h1.inactive {
  color: black;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: "*As you can see Outcome/KPI is not centrally aligned*" - all I can see is a JavaScript error in the console, could you provide the html that your browser’s trying to style? The script generating the html is irrelevant to the css problem you describe, but don’t show.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix would be to centre the text inside each item, by adding the following rule:

```
.innerTabs h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Snippet to demonstrate:

```css
.innerTabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2px;
}

.innerTabs h1 {
  flex: 0 0 calc(16.66% - 20px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="innerTabs">
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred is dead</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
  <h1>Fred</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to set `width` and `height` for the `text` along with `text-align: center`. That will make the `text` part centrally aligned both vertically and horizontally inside each `flex` item. For example:

```
const title = {
  one: "Basic info",
  two: "Validity",
  three: "Diagnostic",
  four:"Outcome/KPI Definitions",
  five: "Outcome Selection",
  six: "Bundle Outcomes",
  seven: "Pricing",
  eight: "Eligible Population"
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="innerTabs">
        {Object.values(title).map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <h1 key={index.toString()}>
              {item}
             </h1>
           )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.innerTabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.innerTabs h1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

A demo is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-agnesi-l5j72q?file=/src/styles.css).